# How to create a web user control in a windows class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need a web feedback widget/usercontrol to be created inside a windows sdk (windows class library) project. User should be able to use this feedback control in their asp.net web application by using this SDK. Is it possible to create an web control inside this class library project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

**Windows Presentation Foundation** ,it generates .xbap file and can easily use in your asp.net web application.It provide good feature.
Recently i used in my application and it's good to go.

Ping me, if you want clarity in it.